# Store and retrieve a password encrypted key after creating and copying exe file to multiple host using C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, encryption, password-protection

I have a scenario where I am trying to develop a small program where user can set a password and than give these same exe file to multiple user to set this password on some others computers.

My problem is: how can I store this encrypted key in hidden text where no other user can get this value? I have tried `setting.settings` file; it works until I copy the exe file and use it on other computer - it lost the data.

I hope I have explained well.

Comment: So the question is: will these copies of the app need to be able to decrypt the password? what exactly do you mean by `to multiple user to set this password on some others computers`?

Comment: for.ex. we have in house window xp embedded system and in this system there are different users (for ex. worker, expert, guest, etc) . using my app manager set some password for all the user and some else copy this exe file and set the password to all the system.

Comment: so: your code will apply the password to the user of Windows OS? Their logon password? or is it a password to use your app?

Comment: yes setting a windows os password for other users.

Comment: since they will use it anyway, why do you need to encrypt it?

Comment: they will use it for once for ex. but after updaing the passowrd they will not able to login to the system without a USB KEY. (http://www.sg-lock.com/en/support.php).  But this is completly differnt topic.. you have already understand what i mean.

Comment: Well if you have the USB key, the whole point of that stick is that it is what stores the encryption key. So your question doesn't make much sense.